# Unknown error message while checking model fit (DHARMa) with inverse.gaussian family in a glmm (lme4)

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to check the model fit of a glmm with an inverse gaussian distribution, using the DHARMa package.

```
library(lme4)
library(DHARMa)

glmm2<-glmer(time ~ noise + md+ (1|id),
        data=data,
        family=inverse.gaussian(link="identity"))
sim<-simulateResiduals(glmm2)
```

Yet, I get this error message:

```
Error in sfun(object, nsim = 1, ftd = rep_len(musim, n * nsim), wts = weights) : 
  could not find function "sfun"
```

However, the code runs fine with other distributions.

This may be the same issue as one posted here: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/284 
After reading this thread, Ben Bolker recently fixed an lme4 issue with the `inverse.gaussian` distribution, yet updating the "lme4" package via `install.packages()` doesn't solve the issue. 
Could this be because the committed fix is not yet on CRAN (only GitHub), or is this be a separate issue entirely?

Here is some data to make a reproducible example (although I don't think it is a problem with this specific data):

```
data<-structure(list(time = c(41.13741586, 9.782034165, 28.43048335, 
3.207626451, 3.28737433, 12.17147616, 6.846317411, 7.060553219, 
9.551505159, 1.946177066, 7.792069828, 3.391127888, 5.691814361, 
6.093369116, 8.293302802, 7.56783162, 3.780120891, 9.783027043, 
4.24972651, 2.876613826, 3.601603686, 29.13667211, 3.424758707, 
3.675592368, 13.0437798, 7.547469641, 8.842781853, 8.300757096, 
2.979181386, 3.419450337, 16.45199251, 3.127217308, 8.747828301, 
3.428571841, 3.70943289, 11.04721516, 2.903853931, 3.440767391, 
2.785837122, 3.269951103, 2.410238878, 3.89081111, 4.619280336, 
2.992322509, 5.783528547, 34.00289472, 24.44992761, 23.23027649, 
9.014569882, 5.894704299, 3.055185939, 2.218424498, 6.382338632, 
2.755323799, 7.076236215, 3.262103618, 3.922126491, 23.61442673, 
18.48894273, 4.800960669, 2.48269627, 3.146589815, 6.439999987, 
7.668507118, 6.419151537, 3.542393771, 3.043635607, 2.884369079, 
2.491696809, 27.55352679, 1.897232137, 2.588586002, 4.559529659, 
5.193832311, 6.66462235, 7.575937154, 4.267289699, 3.077610554, 
2.539769396, 11.04715723, 3.938594629, 2.990035169, 11.62055069, 
6.286390667, 3.066117908, 3.036437669, 14.09709544, 2.247126905, 
3.437216412, 2.22807457, 4.380971792, 2.947254937, 8.787878448, 
3.107896369, 11.28890645, 3.550776501, 7.142133246, 2.362423895, 
4.305386462, 9.045445478, 3.267399008, 4.677552175, 4.718496658, 
3.600337195, 10.44240212, 10.15304052, 9.183458325, 5.928181431, 
25.03263407, 3.076395187, 24.38716969, 2.239600859, 2.172207797, 
8.76376451, 3.183504181, 2.35993369, 8.295343346, 3.418330144, 
3.620356333, 10.54711979, 14.21928106, 10.37029106, 6.031589426, 
3.981959804, 5.342755734, 7.904376564, 5.718102126, 3.410403438, 
9.692149582, 3.13309998, 19.3245972, 4.335996613, 4.841560445, 
12.32188778, 45.52278629, 2.752979722, 12.47383626, 2.134412308, 
14.44585039, 16.10740155, 5.788136583, 4.511246787, 16.7312537, 
3.73230319, 4.897898902, 6.028128975, 52.0381691, 4.068210128, 
6.398227764, 6.118767994, 8.548906531, 3.390646287, 2.490769614, 
4.111526974, 4.832608955, 8.289365702, 50.2465904, 2.646893295, 
9.719880568, 4.641543, 4.771943998, 3.706358115, 4.166786292, 
4.179320836, 19.52129995, 3.174416789, 6.275250101, 3.749363137, 
5.181954223, 5.163764939, 6.324603377, 6.036336947, 2.908604885, 
4.982428475, 6.323173522, 3.64608021, 11.80631532, 3.387963324, 
14.29897945, 3.482688516, 9.645221336, 62.40574289, 3.706740696, 
20.86882567, 3.251831744, 4.462031664, 15.50260099, 6.022609352, 
9.416738158, 8.162124214, 16.92103384, 4.452837389, 33.60315353, 
2.323210606, 4.633791727, 10.51593419, 9.167247429, 3.827658235, 
3.828607871, 3.829411261, 20.42109578, 3.272191767, 13.08373561, 
9.823979107, 2.954488994, 5.89699479, 17.77766321, 14.2193287, 
4.84425791, 3.046470241, 4.376652312, 4.075512895, 4.447326956, 
3.828587987, 3.301959055, 3.266122424, 5.958960708, 9.809333414, 
3.370849736, 3.434066392, 8.531563826, 2.380370139, 11.32306372, 
30.78310772, 3.105894163, 2.326072315, 5.804816817, 45.1877515, 
5.479398096, 3.452887784, 8.392957238, 3.594501224, 4.455098706, 
5.13784923, 4.560898241, 17.59137752, 5.411802079, 6.662678284, 
6.724703395, 3.416384684, 3.478441765, 18.28886191, 16.76116317, 
16.98330296, 12.38336171, 39.52376287, 7.454258623, 4.174623206, 
7.837446903, 4.988091336, 4.781385826, 3.463154542, 3.464226543, 
25.43735658, 3.067537685, 4.258702803, 7.340216019, 49.14047038, 
2.442459709, 9.447392998, 3.197442493, 10.22828166, 4.628425949, 
9.199019126, 3.482760092, 4.764069625, 4.705087528, 8.058345229, 
3.430036022, 66.06439786, 10.77330705, 3.786447776, 10.80383314, 
3.757634691, 17.21945979, 9.280765277, 5.620796286, 3.512069001, 
4.904388737, 6.275277039, 13.81807132, 4.628234066, 2.979297419, 
3.290358325, 10.74032344, 13.65048463, 4.281098604, 8.967766237, 
4.149626936, 2.59, 12.85102282, 23.00134089, 4.814198164, 4.564720885, 
7.195367624, 4.696707842, 9.477280147, 6.887927244, 19.009986, 
4.660588773, 13.41105483, 4.041755049, 3.173568488, 4.533755494, 
21.314069, 6.814173148, 7.955226733, 3.486861445, 28.51746697, 
12.26761549, 47.51824882, 7.208537936, 5.800505255, 3.860646939, 
43.02148852, 18.30155857, 8.401628238, 5.581668235, 40.0252368, 
41.82807892, 15.43939019, 43.93014117, 8.546396018, 18.18405266, 
11.05878955, 6.290103866, 3.290309576, 11.79316794, 12.91487095, 
55.84556727, 4.41720961, 7.462505685, 11.52409499, 9.08413754, 
3.654474629, 3.774640913, 11.77560963, 5.246143327, 4.528003446, 
3.720297554, 26.86158631, 3.121956906, 3.814112187, 3.915468981, 
3.855898118, 6.066957123, 5.818204851, 15.38006946, 4.82077121, 
5.601840547, 8.673335565, 94.57364072, 11.72416331, 3.857151745, 
12.63774199, 3.077864042, 22.91825688, 4.779887153, 3.02290964, 
65.38458973, 14.61544757, 4.589837739, 30.27093406, 8.562364255, 
9.152543612, 7.5945589, 13.78637596, 20.53718869, 15.09996703, 
10.51215369, 22.19312527, 4.103858301, 72.50651558, 5.917881591, 
3.918046252, 25.73809912, 10.11106179, 4.611947838, 3.812338842, 
66.11236733, 3.083073479, 3.923163416, 4.274799646, 5.147559259, 
8.04819077, 7.429203003, 77.1197558, 4.241240055, 18.20449757, 
12.15671963, 12.63195774, 73.33069624, 31.72095844, 6.66150562, 
23.73213392, 4.694739577, 3.798945831, 15.67155682, 10.48168672, 
5.333182065, 4.850010439, 7.652005471, 4.532210133, 4.402485395, 
35.35353175, 3.903941738, 3.184677454, 18.55515345, 2.687618202, 
2.818215173, 10.03921751, 18.5694306, 15.06234012, 7.16657676, 
9.080463855, 22.45095501, 7.831502889, 4.232363182, 66.17311789, 
7.304880603, 6.61580356, 6.178855732, 5.060957087, 8.331560974, 
3.81257565, 4.744033321, 8.284062198, 4.095163125, 50.18527387, 
4.467955136, 7.55798715, 93.1895922, 9.163073489, 4.843419754, 
3.495555564, 21.29713932, 6.607945438, 9.949066825, 5.671821957, 
4.052717444, 4.392775373, 6.805400321, 4.67567415, 3.61639655, 
4.266905617, 6.179724612, 5.499797952, 9.431915978, 61.31221724, 
88.713231, 47.87339455, 4.184470597, 5.814770604, 7.722124227, 
26.91274215, 22.26364589, 10.32376603, 38.02472068, 6.755221955, 
6.655862961, 12.47736033, 3.832455267, 5.794588666, 2.29488901, 
4.825032889, 5.707439328, 8.237935874, 3.398480834, 5.020340238, 
16.54083878, 3.872542885, 88.54425795, 5.625607924, 32.84691682, 
3.567019038, 17.90767527, 4.201325706, 7.412715166, 5.096011771, 
98.45740835, 35.65809944, 6.7282369, 5.479067069, 3.009588285, 
21.26465113, 6.047096921, 24.7085676, 22.26897628, 52.27063039, 
5.302204077, 17.0241899, 5.52564186, 6.185931004, 10.56671436, 
3.498058554, 5.589325271, 12.77965649, 3.449802552, 6.220177507, 
3.650345073, 6.560421815, 65.29056106, 12.65290021, 14.25446065, 
2.534825382, 3.594919078, 6.195722329, 68.28617492, 21.81716823, 
7.727936448, 73.08995666, 7.790689, 5.263312258, 22.09589367, 
9.419771743, 9.770269026, 7.020954402, 23.4026281, 8.625718029, 
18.406882, 4.657678486, 11.65835826, 10.45855645, 6.720511821, 
9.492626932, 20.41736393, 5.287491136, 17.4677231, 47.21784241, 
4.230403918, 6.071208513, 44.32271069, 13.41734888, 47.57801238, 
8.772598635, 9.205175901, 8.55700878, 4.897450519, 4.737495931, 
4.338049612, 6.215468258, 4.165600023, 5.036888453, 9.569007641, 
6.071899787, 7.542304652, 4.732480187, 3.442827096, 41.35375961, 
4.353765853, 3.753951093, 4.664248723, 60.85668314, 80.35729941, 
12.89760767, 3.989420233, 35.96090859, 6.392164591, 4.392808509, 
11.64349675, 15.16356068, 26.66641769, 10.30722888, 4.189055807, 
26.46911323, 19.37062122, 2.591032044, 27.77127424, 12.09154189, 
62.07235295, 5.432750085, 6.406463399, 47.77777956, 7.039493391, 
4.221247722, 68.8818966, 24.38479969, 8.887155651, 12.18805931, 
4.821592099, 15.80203651, 8.702592898, 59.69323291, 6.059270163, 
11.45979501, 39.40068331, 3.901232778, 4.811936493, 5.465225016, 
8.156093384, 3.497747496, 6.628207287, 13.90997849, 10.91123037, 
7.823507377, 17.41400512, 3.335581008, 8.165933257, 8.858253615, 
3.11079724, 11.54130872, 8.642978559, 9.713731749, 4.457465386, 
20.51801412, 7.558962511, 19.09083352, 3.111885984, 4.773125492, 
3.936568118, 5.317176674, 23.43778227, 15.63826616, 36.44002133, 
13.38015732, 5.292505485, 4.783865063, 22.66444017, 20.60565127, 
11.78703337, 10.74863376, 22.88895906, 16.73011321, 4.040348858, 
4.304943155, 5.026492863, 10.01713706, 5.648188872, 7.178448492, 
3.460327443, 15.40073695, 2.682902487, 5.774015487, 67.56871224, 
18.67961631, 5.100519708, 8.061332641, 5.132089571, 32.47386136, 
9.414060145, 7.254471895, 10.75556407, 5.658317047, 11.56855848, 
10.92050226, 7.863734311, 44.48384677, 7.864493752, 16.73642175, 
35.13153666, 2.83164151, 89.49256856, 9.29474009, 3.344889429, 
23.59843601, 15.66216937, 3.34173857, 5.943488483, 51.65482739, 
55.39614187, 9.007741113, 5.787799271, 9.848206998, 7.538856381, 
5.3796996, 9.950124408, 9.330343418, 5.311483191, 6.261800614, 
11.45253276, 11.48741207, 18.04993558, 87.72143563, 23.92329284, 
5.715208533, 3.116109407, 3.526837879, 7.089243781, 3.839410349, 
3.380133647, 35.83050327, 45.93174123, 6.824078926, 4.974603407, 
64.13461403, 13.5354574, 4.186924017, 7.010327493, 60.94089111, 
7.953126298, 7.763630404, 4.355139132, 8.766348864, 8.297972846, 
5.489028514, 16.14967745, 20.55160891, 9.801691177, 24.05331142, 
3.054056576, 6.356113769, 4.526387275, 41.05646944, 87.15748558, 
3.087562276, 11.55760686, 41.55854476, 6.389576519, 41.56061368, 
8.631088213, 3.561678389, 3.412607997, 5.433127705, 13.46547347, 
8.016249869, 11.18752614, 16.80909843, 7.509632253, 6.200475612, 
8.00121421, 4.92138598, 7.852715585, 17.13290285, 5.853321497, 
2.704434081, 83.67600754, 21.60982366, 72.68196408, 4.86197169, 
6.143998414, 5.984085597, 65.7869803, 17.43792585, 14.28896726, 
5.339398457, 7.309532293, 5.8, 20.68070572, 4.440736792, 13.19366278, 
62.89981678, 4.4, 31.40239036, 12.29444914, 7.385797172, 10.19820787, 
8.893010935, 7.273767797, 30.61441959, 10.995188, 80.21558756, 
67.91582164, 4.216706087, 9.11802591, 13.41809671, 38.11920761, 
26.81937129, 8.399840607, 31.41988565, 5.970228522, 14.62953905, 
6.906308231, 46.42810685, 4.259323889, 7.90956253, 12.69999747, 
9.941220655, 5.611597938, 4.101697356, 4.97251454, 3.29426027, 
5.674547381, 7.135133419, 4.32571262, 11.23584732, 5.356806181, 
21.1381246, 5.640204077, 50.64098656, 21.74196711, 7.114049809, 
69.14405789, 11.08407918, 9.614960631, 6.305296022, 9.425762636, 
3.586616832, 3.987438688, 4.707836204, 13.98798518, 49.25125373, 
12.6221062, 5.775052381, 7.006755171, 43.65712799, 14.24896706, 
13.09035569, 5.603557141, 7.363880162, 4.604196486, 6.604373673, 
4.825110605, 10.38589501, 17.66593416, 8.006941271, 4.158453861, 
30.85879709, 13.21918021, 10.67157215, 6.241612269, 98.17192465, 
32.67287969, 4.983331185, 20.29372069, 4.804043711, 4.266221754, 
7.117825467, 13.19915511, 5.989386148, 3.930709804, 4.522719284, 
3.872789982, 5.934531644, 48.88519892, 4.995590229, 10.71702774, 
58.18713996, 5.408302428, 7.210063546, 34.49123805, 7.791664114, 
4.784022296, 13.19515942, 5.565235072, 18.58556714, 35.69660968, 
6.817019169, 49.69835067, 5.162957511, 9.423694931, 16.73454058, 
37.50499864, 3.545501923, 4.086844008, 5.158503892, 11.30946687, 
6.339981148, 5.402200808, 60.7157093, 8.996041752, 4.716424861, 
4.746533209, 32.03878257, 5.183617664, 13.52553971, 25.8217186, 
6.283448511, 5.283619437, 4.663705606, 4.784524026, 37.72518574, 
7.475938419, 4.256979349, 6.747055688, 5.389175626, 5.789724431, 
3.890042036, 9.230814747, 5.830958808, 10.17128062, 97.2313699, 
4.891389037, 4.032935801, 6.073353203, 7.983586247, 13.92732222, 
4.387520417, 10.6082623, 57.7389435, 10.9914034, 6.372993563, 
5.864494002, 37.24617264, 7.746659158, 4.558902538, 7.149688515, 
5.721092216, 3.031219963, 6.881457428, 5.401788271, 18.4342511, 
5.034322669, 5.823274353, 9.895358183, 5.606547324, 12.17744259, 
8.990127566, 7.144633101, 5.840023387, 14.22145227, 3.661540144, 
31.78595354, 60.78602018, 9.568657786, 6.589606217, 11.5004296, 
11.26096657, 3.7317475, 25.79324716, 6.545466266, 37.7943937, 
7.044451557, 6.626310111, 6.69666011, 14.07726794, 5.477346607, 
12.88805136, 53.79825342, 42.80146828, 6.402334652, 5.99360942, 
33.80524434, 6.40734361, 20.80743047, 8.030528537, 51.41054388, 
3.750730015, 8.742226584, 5.312386607, 8.943284188, 4.753595783, 
51.41416859, 6.345055058, 4.156655336, 7.06692512, 5.198644681, 
10.73224033, 10.66319026, 3.673375589, 6.633472681, 30.22377284, 
10.92891361, 37.02492114, 3.667219484, 54.02734635, 12.10764859, 
10.04801493, 6.57970909, 41.83188115, 5.08416902, 4.295467738, 
5.370520688, 62.8468498, 71.04833317, 7.568852093, 7.409029886, 
11.97942712, 5.160546297, 34.05225643, 84.75282622, 6.063497811, 
4.663622269, 64.75434338, 5.275457924, 4.267158793, 19.85760569, 
38.8584257, 5.450269513, 19.66255491, 90.3618477, 15.36214503, 
7.193836378, 45.46389467, 12.66542026, 5.485897332, 9.179153293, 
5.149186649, 6.729612253, 10.83999684, 8.430694187, 7.311419643, 
17.17267499, 21.79455081, 5.344759649, 4.295641456, 9.466075813, 
20.16667645, 13.34790152, 10.37801212, 62.37881405, 44.02705672, 
6.281168569, 7.602319351, 11.60387192, 13.1849234, 5.605190238, 
5.855195352, 21.38760878, 3.88769096, 7.078750029), noise = c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L), id = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Anshin", "Cartman", "Chiarah", "Mucki"
), class = "factor"), md = c(8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.66, 2, 16, 
1, 4, 1, 8, 1, 5.66, 2.83, 8, 16, 4, 8, 1, 16, 4, 2, 2.83, 1, 
1, 8, 2.83, 2, 16, 8, 8, 5.66, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5.66, 16, 1, 5.66, 
5.66, 16, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 2, 1, 5.66, 16, 2, 8, 8, 5.66, 5.66, 
4, 8, 2, 16, 16, 1, 2, 8, 8, 2.83, 4, 8, 2.83, 16, 16, 5.66, 
16, 8, 5.66, 8, 1, 5.66, 5.66, 8, 2, 1, 8, 16, 2, 16, 16, 8, 
2.83, 4, 5.66, 4, 2.83, 1, 16, 2.83, 1, 8, 16, 16, 2, 16, 8, 
16, 16, 2, 8, 16, 1, 1, 16, 8, 5.66, 2, 8, 2, 5.66, 2.83, 1, 
5.66, 2, 5.66, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2.83, 2, 4, 4, 1, 8, 5.66, 2, 4, 4, 
8, 2.83, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5.66, 1, 16, 1, 5.66, 2.83, 2.83, 4, 8, 
8, 16, 4, 4, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2.83, 5.66, 2.83, 2.83, 1, 2, 5.66, 
4, 5.66, 8, 1, 16, 5.66, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5.66, 16, 1, 5.66, 5.66, 
2.83, 2.83, 2, 2, 2.83, 2.83, 2, 8, 4, 8, 2, 16, 2, 5.66, 16, 
4, 2.83, 4, 5.66, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 8, 2, 1, 4, 2.83, 2, 5.66, 2, 
2, 2.83, 8, 1, 4, 8, 4, 8, 8, 5.66, 4, 16, 2, 2.83, 1, 16, 2.83, 
8, 1, 8, 4, 4, 1, 8, 2, 5.66, 8, 8, 4, 8, 1, 4, 2.83, 16, 16, 
2, 1, 2, 16, 2, 16, 16, 8, 2.83, 16, 1, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
2, 16, 16, 2.83, 5.66, 4, 2.83, 8, 2, 5.66, 2, 1, 2.83, 4, 1, 
4, 8, 8, 2, 1, 8, 2.83, 8, 2.83, 5.66, 4, 2.83, 5.66, 2.83, 1, 
2, 8, 1, 2.83, 8, 2.83, 4, 5.66, 2.83, 2, 16, 2.83, 8, 4, 16, 
4, 2.83, 16, 1, 2, 2.83, 16, 2, 16, 2.83, 16, 5.66, 4, 2.83, 
1, 2, 8, 5.66, 2, 8, 16, 1, 2.83, 5.66, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 16, 
4, 2, 8, 1, 4, 5.66, 2, 4, 5.66, 1, 2, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 16, 2.83, 
16, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2.83, 4, 4, 2, 16, 8, 8, 4, 8, 2, 8, 5.66, 16, 
1, 1, 1, 4, 2.83, 2.83, 2, 2.83, 8, 1, 4, 16, 5.66, 4, 8, 1, 
8, 4, 4, 16, 2.83, 1, 1, 8, 16, 5.66, 5.66, 16, 16, 2, 2, 5.66, 
16, 2.83, 4, 5.66, 1, 8, 4, 2.83, 2, 2.83, 4, 2, 8, 1, 5.66, 
1, 8, 1, 1, 16, 16, 4, 16, 4, 2, 2.83, 4, 4, 5.66, 5.66, 16, 
4, 2, 8, 8, 8, 1, 8, 5.66, 5.66, 16, 16, 1, 2, 2, 16, 1, 4, 1, 
1, 5.66, 5.66, 2, 4, 16, 1, 1, 4, 16, 2, 1, 2.83, 1, 2, 4, 4, 
2, 2, 16, 2, 16, 1, 4, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 16, 2, 1, 16, 2, 2, 4, 
5.66, 2, 1, 1, 8, 16, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8, 1, 2, 2, 2.83, 2.83, 8, 
2, 2.83, 2.83, 2, 2.83, 1, 5.66, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 16, 
1, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 16, 5.66, 2, 5.66, 5.66, 2, 1, 5.66, 8, 2.83, 
16, 2.83, 1, 16, 16, 4, 4, 2.83, 5.66, 16, 16, 2.83, 16, 8, 4, 
2.83, 16, 8, 8, 5.66, 2, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 1, 5.66, 8, 2.83, 5.66, 
8, 2, 4, 5.66, 8, 16, 1, 16, 4, 2, 16, 2.83, 2.83, 4, 5.66, 4, 
1, 16, 2, 5.66, 1, 2.83, 5.66, 2, 2, 5.66, 8, 5.66, 1, 1, 2, 
4, 5.66, 2, 4, 1, 5.66, 16, 1, 8, 2.83, 4, 16, 2, 16, 16, 8, 
1, 4, 4, 5.66, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5.66, 1, 5.66, 4, 1, 1, 16, 5.66, 
1, 1, 5.66, 4, 8, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5.66, 2, 5.66, 2.83, 4, 5.66, 
5.66, 16, 4, 5.66, 4, 8, 2.83, 16, 1, 5.66, 8, 5.66, 16, 4, 16, 
2, 2.83, 2, 1, 2.83, 1, 5.66, 2.83, 2, 1, 2.83, 4, 16, 2, 16, 
2, 2.83, 1, 16, 4, 2.83, 5.66, 2.83, 1, 5.66, 8, 4, 8, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 4, 5.66, 16, 2.83, 16, 16, 2, 5.66, 2, 8, 16, 2, 8, 16, 
2.83, 16, 2, 8, 1, 5.66, 1, 5.66, 5.66, 16, 1, 16, 16, 1, 2, 
5.66, 16, 1, 2, 5.66, 2.83, 1, 16, 5.66, 1, 1, 2.83, 1, 4, 4, 
2, 1, 2, 2.83, 4, 5.66, 2.83, 2, 2.83, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 16, 8, 
4, 4, 16, 5.66, 5.66, 1, 4, 5.66, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2.83, 1, 2, 8, 16, 5.66, 8, 4, 5.66, 4, 1, 1, 2, 16, 8, 4, 4, 
2.83, 4, 8, 16, 16, 4, 5.66, 5.66, 4, 8, 2, 4, 5.66, 1, 2, 5.66, 
8, 16, 2.83, 2, 1, 5.66, 1, 2.83, 5.66, 2.83, 16, 16, 2, 2, 16, 
16, 1, 1, 5.66, 2.83, 1, 16, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 16, 5.66, 5.66, 1, 
16, 5.66, 2, 16, 1, 16, 1, 1, 8, 16, 5.66, 5.66, 5.66, 16, 16, 
5.66, 5.66, 5.66, 4, 1, 8, 4, 5.66, 1, 8, 2, 8, 2, 5.66, 4, 16, 
5.66, 5.66, 2.83, 5.66, 8, 8, 1, 16, 16, 2, 4, 8, 5.66, 2, 5.66, 
16, 2, 4, 16, 8, 1, 2.83, 1, 1, 2.83, 1, 8, 2, 16, 1, 4, 8, 5.66, 
1, 8, 16, 2, 4, 16, 5.66, 2.83, 4, 8, 4, 4, 16, 16, 2.83, 8, 
5.66, 5.66, 16, 16, 16, 1, 2.83, 4, 2, 2.83, 4, 1, 2, 16, 2.83, 
16, 4, 8, 2, 5.66, 2, 2.83, 4, 2, 2.83, 2, 16, 2.83, 5.66, 4, 
1, 1, 2.83, 2.83, 1, 2.83, 8, 5.66, 4, 4, 5.66, 1, 8, 16, 5.66, 
5.66, 2.83, 2, 16, 2.83, 1, 5.66, 4, 4, 2.83, 2, 4, 16, 2.83, 
2.83, 16, 8, 2.83, 2.83, 8, 4, 5.66, 8, 2.83, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2.83, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 2, 8, 8, 5.66, 16, 2.83)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1000L))
```

(see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254361/modeling-reaction-time-with-glmer for explanation on why this particular distribution for response time data. Original paper here: https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.01171)